# Widely Supported Regex look behind

Tags: javascript, regex

Is There is any pattern equal to 
(?<=) or (?

**Goal:** capture specific middle of string in multi line mode.
The Left or Right side can be only [a-zA-Z].

- axxb => pass capture xx
- 2xxb => fail
- @xxb => fail

Note: (xx) is a specific characters!

Answer (score 1):

Use `[a-zA-Z](xx)[a-zA-Z]` and get group 1

```js
var test = [
    'axxb',
    '2xxb',
    '@xxb',

];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a + ' :' + a.match(/[a-zA-Z](xx)[a-zA-Z]/);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is look-behind in js. Only problem is not supported in all browsers.
Chrome yes, not sure about others. Also support in browsers is not covered by [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Browser_support)

You can look on this [mini example](https://regex101.com/r/MyVFql/2/) - should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine lookahead and lookbehind:

https://regex101.com/r/VTKSH8/1

The above captures the second `x` in the last two examples because they match - you can make the regex match two or more characters in the middle as well:

https://regex101.com/r/5ThvGd/1

Note: It's on Regex101 because it doesn't work on Stack Snippets

Comment: xx is a specific characters not any characters in the middle.

Comment: This works only in Chrome. Other browsers don't support lookbehind